# Joomla External Domain Problem

Tags: php, apache, web-services, joomla, joomla1.5

I've got a problem with Joomla 1.5.+, hope you can help me.

I installed it on a server which is in an internal DMZ and want to access it via an internet domain. The problem is that some references on the site still point to the internal domain. I've read that in the earlier Mamboo-days of Joomla a variable "$mosConfig_live_site" existed which let me somehow "workaround" the problem.
Unfortunately this variable nowadays doesn't exist any more on Joomla.

Now here is the question.. Can i set a variable (ether database or in the config.php or sth else) in which i can set the external domain, so that the generated template will use it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$mosConfig_live_site must have changed to $live_site in your configuration.php file. If you set it to something like http://yourserver/subdomain it changes some links, at least.

I guess it all depends on if it changes the right ones...

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
JURI::base();
```

Comment: Can you explain that a little bit more ?